# MBP shuts down at 40%~ battery, and recalibration didn't help

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

**EDIT: I don't think this is a duplicate question. My MBP is only 2 years old and its battery cycle count is only 90.**

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) with macOS 10.12.6, and there is a battery issue.

It shuts down when there is still 40%~ battery left.

I tried to [reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [recalibrate the battery](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-service-battery-warning-mac/). I followed all the instructions, but I don't even know how I can be sure if the SMC reset was successful.

More importantly, the recalibration was not helpful at all.

macOS still gives me the warning "Service Battery", and as shown in the screenshot attached, coconutBattery reports 60%~ in the "Design Capacity" section. It shuts down at 40%~ battery as before.

Why is the MBP battery like this despite the not-that-high battery cycle count (90)?

Is going to an Apple service center the only option I have? Are there any other things I can try by myself?

Thank you.

[image: coconutBattery]

Comment: It’s a dupe.  The vintage of the Macs in question have nothing to do with the symptoms which are a tell-tale sign your battery is bad.  Having only 90 cycles doesn’t make it immune from being a defect (it has failed cells).

Comment: @Allan I'm not saying it's supposed to be immune. Part of my question was **why**, i.e. **what could be the cause of** this battery disaster, because neither the age nor the battery cycle count explains it. Was the battery already faulty when I bought it? Have I been using it wrong?

Comment: I agree with @Allan and have rejected your edit because it doesn't change things in terms of your battery. I do understand your battery cycle count is only 90, but it's really not uncommon for batteries to exceed or fall short of their life expectancy. However, it may very well be worth going to Apple and getting them to take a look (I know I would be). You never know your *luck* with these things, especially if the consumer laws in your jurisdiction still offer you some coverage.